# What is the best way to store database username and password in microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

While developing microservice (for e.g. spring boot service), we are storing database username and password in properties file. Microservice would connect to database using these database credentials.

1. Is there any other best way to store database username and password ?
2. What are best techniques to store database user and password securely in encrypted format and how to decrypt before connecting to database schema?

We are using Chef Cookbook (DevOps), Chef Client for deployment of microservices in Amazon Web Services(AWS)

Comment: As always, the answer is: it depends. How do you deploy your microservices? If you're using Kubernetes, you could use secrets for passwords. You could even use `ConfigMap` for `application.yaml` and reconfigure service without redeploying everything. Other platforms might have other solutions. You should specify your enviroment.

Comment: We are using Chef Cookbook (DevOps), Chef Client for deployment of microservices in Amazon Web Services(AWS)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to have a Config Server to which your applications connect and get their configurations at startup time. This Config Server might decrypt the encrypted sensitive data.

A simple example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/